# Meteor React infinite scroll: Stop Component from refreshing

Tags: reactjs, meteor, page-refresh, meteor-publications

I am using Meteor with React. I have a component which is wrapped in a react-composer to subscribe to my data. I set the limit on the server publication to 10 and enhance this limit every time a user scrolls to a button by another 10.

The problem is, that instead of adding just the 10 new elements to the view the whole componentes seems to refresh. How can I reactivly reload only the additional data, without making a total "page" refresh?

---

In principal I use javascript to detect when the user reached the bottom of the page and then fire a function in the parents component to change the limit-state of my LocationList, which then triggers the publication of the server to load more locations.

**Server/Publication.js**

```
Meteor.publish("Locations", function(settings) {
  check(settings, Object);
  ReactiveAggregate(this, Locations, [
    { $limit: settings.limit },
    { $project: {
      name: '$name',
    }},
  ]);
});
```

**client/LocationList.jsx**

```
class LocationList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  handleScroll() {
    const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    const body = document.body;
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,  html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;
    if (windowBottom >= docHeight - 100) {
      // bottom reached
      this.props.onLoadMore();
    } else {
      // not bottom
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  render() {
     ... something
  }
}

function composer(props, onData) {
  const settings = {
    limit: props.limit,
  };

  const locationSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('Locations', settings);

  if(locationSubscription.ready()) {
    locations = Locations.find({}, {limit: props.limit}).fetch();

    const data = {
      ready: true,
      locations: locations,
    }
    onData(null, data);
  } else {
    onData(null, {ready: false});
  }
}

const options = {
  loadingHandler: () => (<p>Loading... </p>)
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer, options)(LocationList);
```

**client/LocationListLoader.jsx**

```
export default class LocationListLoader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      limit: 9
    };

    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.category != nextProps.category) {
      this.setState({ limit: 9 });
    }
  }

  loadMore() {
    const newLimit = this.state.limit + 6;
    this.setState({ limit: newLimit });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LocationList onLoadMore={this.loadMore} limit={this.state.limit} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you share the code for more details ?

Comment: Sure! Here you go.

Comment: Add 'loadingMore` prop and don't call `this.props.onLoadMore();` if it's already in progress. `windowBottom >= docHeight - 100` will be true and called many times.

Comment: @elmeister I am aware of that and will fix it! But the main problem is that somehow the whole page is refreshing, with every single call of `onLoadMore()`. I guess that the cached local Mongo DB is completely refreshed when changing the publication? I also tried to publish ALL data and then set a limit on the client subscription and this seems to be working perfectly fine!

Comment: Check if any props of `LocationListLoader` or higher component were changed. This package may help https://github.com/garbles/why-did-you-update. Also add `key` to your `<LocationListLoader />`. To prevent re-render with upper component.